# In SQL, how can I select the value in a row for every user, but only the most up-to-date row by comparing a time property?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has properties userid, value, and time, representing setting some value for the user. I want to make a table that has the userids and values but only for the latest time. For instance, if you have on row that says "green" at time 40, and another that says "blue" at time 50 for the same user, then the result of the query should say "blue". Here's an example of how I tried to do it, but user 6 still says "green" even though the property "blue" was a later time.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87817/1

What should you do to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by finding the `MAX(time)` for each `userid` in a subquery, then joining to that to find the `value` associated with the latest `time`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Persons p
JOIN (SELECT userid
             ,MAX(time) as latest_time
      FROM Persons
      GROUP BY userid
      ) sub
 ON p.userid = sub.userid
 AND p.time = sub.latest_time
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87817/10/0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're getting `max(value)`. Alphabetically `Green` is bigger than `Blue`. If you change your query to `min(value)` then you'll get Blue for user 6. This doesn't fix your problem.

To fix your problem, you need to do either a CTE or a sub select. Somethign like this:

```
SELECT Persons.userid, MAX(value) as latest_value,
  MAX(time) as latest_time
  FROM Persons
  JOIN (
         select userid, max(time) as latest_time
         from Persons
         group by userid
    ) subSelect 
  ON subSelect.userid = persons.userid and latest_time = time
  GROUP BY userid;
```